# Working in Visual Studio (2005 or 2008) on a networked drive

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

Have you guys had any experiences (positive or negative) by placing your source code/solution on a network drive for Visual Studio 2005 or 2008?  Please note I am not referring to placing your actual source control system on that drive, but rather your working folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works just fine. I have worked with source code from my "home" folder on many different systems (NFS, Samba, AD) and never had any problems. The only drawback is that you might experience somewhat longer compile times if your network is slow or there is much traffic on the network. Under normal circumstances this is not an issue though, since source code files are usually small and will be cached by the operating system anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Some folks in our company do that with their external dependencies, and they get occasional build errors, usually because a library or header can't be retrieved. When they rebuild again it all works. Of course the speed and traffic-level of your network would have a major effect on this.